# Integral of 5 and $\phi$

Tags: integration, golden-ratio

> $$\int_{0}^{\phi}{(1-x+x^2-x^3)^{2N-1}\over\left[1-(2N+1)x+(4N+1)x^2-(6N+1)x^3\right]^{-1}}\mathrm dx =5^{N}\phi\tag1$$

suppose $N\ge1$ and $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

> How do we show that it does evaluate to $5^N\phi?$

Substitution doesn't seem to work  for this integral. Unless we change these into a sum but how?

$$1-(2N+1)x+(4N+1)x^2-(6N+1)x^3$$
and

$$1-x+x^2-x^3$$

Comment: Is it really intentional to divide by $[\cdots]^{-1}$? Division by the inverse of a number is the same as multiplying with that number...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)=1-x+x^2-x^3$.

Then, $$1-(2N+1)x+(4N+1)x^2-(6N+1)x^3$$
can be written as
$$\begin{align}&1-(2N+1)x+(4N+1)x^2-(6N+1)x^3\\\\&=1-x+x^2-x^3+2Nx(-1+2x-3x^2)\\\\&=f(x)+2Nxf'(x)\end{align}$$

Using this, we have
$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\phi}f^{2N-1}(x)(f(x)+2Nxf'(x))\ \mathrm dx&=\int_{0}^{\phi}\left(f^{2N}(x)+x\left(f^{2N}(x)\right)'\right)\ \mathrm dx\\\\&=\int_{0}^{\phi}\left(xf^{2N}(x)\right)'\ \mathrm dx\\\\&=\left[xf^{2N}(x)\right]_{0}^{\phi}\\\\&=\phi(1-\phi+\phi^2-\phi^3)^{2N}\\\\&=5^N\phi\end{align}$$

The last equality comes from that
$$1-\phi+\phi^2-\phi^3=(1-\phi)(1+\phi^2)=(1-\phi)(2+\phi)=2-\phi-(\phi+1)=-\sqrt 5$$
where we used that $\phi^2=1+\phi$.